# Does $\int_a^\infty f$ exist iff $\int_a^\infty |f|$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

My question is, does $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ exist if and only if $\int_a^\infty |f(x)|dx$ converges?

Since $$\left|\int_a^\infty f(x)dx\right|\leq \int_a^\infty |f(x)|dx,$$ it's obvious that if $\int_a^\infty |f(x)|$ exists, then $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ also exists. But I'm not sure about the converse.

Comment: What is $a$ here? Any real number?

Comment: Lebesgue integral or improper Riemann integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the Riemann integral:  no. For instance, let

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1+x^2} & x \in A \\
\frac{-1}{1+x^2} & x \notin A \\
\end{cases}
$$
where $A$ is the rationals. Then the integral of the absolute value exists, but the integral of $f$ does not.

Comment: Thanks. I have to show in an exercise that if $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ exists and if $\ell:=\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ exists, then $\ell=0$. I suppose by contradiction that $\ell>0$, and then there is an $M>a$ s.t. $|f(x)|>\frac{\ell}{2}$ and thus, if $x>M$, $$\int_a^x |f(t)|dt>\int_a^M|f(t)|dt+\int_M^x\frac{\ell}{2}=\int_a^M|f(x)|dx+\frac{\ell}{2}(x-M)\to \infty $$ if $x\to\infty $. But actually, it's a contradiction with the fact that $\int_a^\infty |f|$ converge, not $\int_a^\infty f$. So how can I prove this result ?

Comment: I have no idea...but you might want to ask *that* question rather than the one you did ask.

Comment: @idm: Since $\ell>0$, there is $M$ s.t. $f(x)>\tfrac \ell2$ for $x>M$. No need to bring absolute value into this.

Comment: you right, great :-)

Answer (score 3):

Think about the analogous question for sums.  The alternating harmonic sum:
$$1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 +...$$
converges (any alternating series with terms decreasing, in absolute value, to 0 converges).  But the corresponding positive series diverges.

Comment: ... which suggests that a nice smooth counterexample here would be $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. This gives rise to the [Sine Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral), whose value between $0$ and $\infty$ is $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $L^1(\Omega,\Bbb C):=\{f:\Omega\to\Bbb C\;\;\mbox{meas. s.t.}\;\;\int_{\Omega}|f|dm<+\infty\}$, where $dm$ is the Lebesgue measure (and $\Omega$ a measurable subset of $\Bbb R^n$), thus when integrating à la Lebesgue the answer to your question is yes.

If otherwise we integrate à la Riemann the answer is no: just consider $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}x$ over $]0,+\infty[$: $\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx<+\infty$ but $\int_0^{+\infty}|f(x)|dx=+\infty$.